# matplolib, x-axis are overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlapping

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("traffic.csv", delimiter=',', encoding="utf8",dtype=None)
plt.hist(data[1:,2])
plt.show()
```

So, basically it overlaps, and I want it to be simplified.
[image]

[csv link](http://drnam.org/pythonfiles/traffic.csv)

Comment: This cannot be the code that generated the image as it leads to the error message `plt.hist(data[1:,2]) IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2`. However, you should import with `dtype="float"` to avoid that you have an array of string values.

Comment: Try this: `plt.hist([float(x) for x in data[1:,2]])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MaxNLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) to set the maximum number of ticks that will fit on nicely.